# Mouse issue while gaming

Tags: mouse, gaming, wireless-mouse

### Background story:

So I got a wireless mouse a long time ago. It's a Delux M371. Some time ago the mouse started reacting very slowly and sometimes it just didn't react. I decided that this mouse was dead and replaced it with a new mouse. **Everything was working.**

---

One day I had to replace my 2nd mouse with the Delux one. It was working again. I replaced its batteries with brand-new ones and continued using it.

---

### My problem:

So as I am playing League of Legends (or some other games) the mouse reacts slowly or just stops responding. **The moment I stop playing, everything is back to normal.**

---

I doubt it's a battery issue. It may be a driver or hardware one. It may be something else.

### My question:

What can cause these issues?

---

### Additional info:

OS: Windows XP SP3/Ubuntu 13.10
CPU: Intel Pentium e2160 (1.80GHz)
RAM: 2x512 MB RAM
Motherboard:asus P5LD2 SE
Mouse: Delux M371

Comment: Have you checked the game specifications with your computer specifications? Most likely it's an underpowered computer with a graphics card that can't keep up, and your computer gets a hard time keeping up with your game.

Comment: The game is running OK with my other mouse